# MySQLi vs PDO - execução de query/funções

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Olhando perguntas aqui do stack e o site do php.net, vi que as execuções de query/funções no MySQLi usa `if()` para verificar se ela foi ou não executada, e as do PDO usa `try { ... } cacth() { ... }`, exemplo de conexão com banco de acordo com a documentação do PHP

MySQLi:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

PDO:

```
<?php
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Por que?
Tem algum problema usar invertido?

Comment: Na mysqli você pode optar por usar exceção ou não nativamente. Na PDO é o mecanismo normal. Lançar exceção à toa (como num erro de DB) eu entendo como falha de entendimento do mecanismo, em prol de "modas" de programação (as tais "boas práticas", que só são boas de verdade no mundo acadêmico). Exceção em PHP normalmente é algo digno de Rube Goldberg

Comment: Para usar com mysqli: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php em especial a flag `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` que faz com que a mysqli use exceções

Comment: @Bacco pode fazer uma resposta exemplificando como tratar os possíveis erros (`Exception`)? Com uma lista de erros e explicando o que é cada um

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independente de qual opção tomar, como ativar configuração no My ou If é importante saber que quando se *invoca* o Try..Catch significa que o PHP (no caso) entra em modo de alerta e se prepara, caso algo **inesperado** venha a ocorrer, evitando por exemplo um *estouro de pilha*. Ou seja, não convém usar esse método para tudo, um If sempre será mais performático.

Answer (score 2):

Para o PDO é fácil e a própria documentação explica:

> PDO::__construct() throws a PDOException if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails.

como o retorno do PDO, em caso de erro, é uma exceção, usar `try...catch` é recomendado.

Agora, a documentação do `mysqli_connect` é vaga quanto ao retorno. Mas, testando rapidamente se sabe que o retorno é um boolean e em caso negativo o erro ficará disponível em `mysqli_connect_error`. Pelo tipo de retorno não se faz necessário um bloco `try..catch`, embora se possa usar:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

try {
    if (!$link) {
        throw new RuntimeException(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
} catch (RuntimeException $exception) {
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE** Ou, conforme sugerido por @Bacco, usando `mysqli_report` e forçando exceções de serem lançadas em caso de erros:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
    $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // caso haja um problema com a conexão, uma exceção será lançada
}
```

Como, conforme o manual, `mysqli_connect` é um atalho para [`mysqli::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), podemos observar que o retorno deveria ser um objeto representando a conexão, mas não é para chamadas diretamente via `mysqli_connect`:

> Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server.

Em termos práticos: use `try..catch` com o PDO, uma vez que sem isso um erro não poderá ser contido e tratado e use ou `if` ou `try..catch` para mysqli, pois ambos podem ser usados.

**Fontes:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php

Comment: Te alguma vantagem usar `try catch` no mysqli em relação ao `if()`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, depende da forma que tua aplicação está sendo feita. Com exceptions tu deixa a linguagem cuidando disso por ti, com ifs, você vai tendo que incluir durante seus códigos, seja durante a conexão com o banco ou durante um query, por exemplo. Ambos acabarão tendo o mesmo resultado, de qualquer forma.

Comment: @Bacco adicionei um update tratando do `mysqli_report`. Obrigado.

Comment: Beleza, mas nem precisa deixar os créditos a mim não. Comentei só pra não deixar a informação incompleta.