# Script "mais bonito"

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou utlizando o seguinte codigo para a class Usuario :

```
<?php
    class Usuario {
        public $nome, $email;
        private $senha;
        private $mysqli;

        public function __construct($nome, $email, $senha){
            $this->nome = $nome;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->senha = $senha;
            $this->conectar();
            $this->validarUsuario();
        }
        public function conectar(){
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','escritor');
        }
        public function validarUsuario(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$this->email' and senha='$this->senha'";
            $resultado = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

            if(!$resultado){$this->erro();}

            if($resultado->num_rows == 0){
                echo "nao existe usuario";
            }else{
                echo "existe usuario";
            }
        }
        public function insertUsuario(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$this->email'";
            $resultado = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

            if(!$resultado){
                $this->erro();
            }

            if($resultado->num_rows == 1){
                echo "email em uso";
                exit();
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user(nome,email,senha) VALUES('$this->nome','$this->email','$this->senha')";
            $resultado = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

            if(!$resultado){
                $this->erro();
            }

            echo "registrado com sucesso";
        }
        public function erro(){
            echo "<p>Erro</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

Teria alguma forma do script fica menor e "mais bonito" ?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Recomendo: https://www.php-fig.org/ **e** https://www.owasp.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe um certo, nem sempre tornar o código menor pode te ajudar (exemplo: a falta de Try Catch pode prejudicar o tratamento de erros). Outros Exemplos:

1. Crie uma classe para armazenar os `Scripts SQL` separado e fazer as vinculações;
2. Não **concatene** $this->email com a query, pois pode resultar em Injection
   https://www.tecmundo.com.br/tecmundo-explica/113195-sql-injection-saiba-tudo-ataque-simples-devastador.htm
3. Em caso de **Remove ou Update**, retorne sempre true em caso de sucesso, ou false, em caso de falha no banco, trazendo a responsabilidade de tratar os resultados para o servlet, ou outra camada que chamou esse método;
4. Em caso de **Insert**, você pode retornar o ID, do registro que acabou de ser criada no banco, para isso você irá precisar trabalhar com transação;
5. Utilize sempre **Try Catch** para tratar as exceções toda a vez que for realizar alguma conexão com o banco;
6. (opcional) Prefira utilizar **PDO** em vez de **Mysqli**, por questão de ser Orientada a Objeto, e funcionar com diversos banco de dados diferentes. [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8302/mysqli-vs-pdo-qual-o-mais-recomendado-para-usar).

Exemplo:

```
    public function conectar(){
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=escritor", "root", ""); 
    }
    public function insertUsuario(){
        try{
          $this->connection->beginTransaction();
          $stmt = Sqls::insercaoUsuarios($this->connection,$this->email,$this->nome,$this->senha);
          if($stmt->execute()){
              $lastid = $this->connection->lastInsertId();
              $this->connection->commit();
              return $lastid;
           }
        } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
           $this->connection->rollback(); 
           echo $e->getMessage(); 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

No caso Sqls::insercaoUsuarios irá realizar somente a criação de uma statement PDO, pronta para ser executada.

$this->connection seria da Classe `PDO` que realiza a conexão com o banco de dados, e `$stmt` da classe `PDOStatement`

Comment: pode me mostrar como ficaria o script com as suas especificações ?

Comment: Eu achei que o código iria ficar maior que isso, mas foi porque verificar se já existe um usuário cadastro, você deve colocar em método separado, questão de tornar reutilizável

Comment: Em relação ao uso do [`try catch`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280325), só é necessário no PDO, talvez você possa deixar o seu código mais organizado usando o padrão DAO (mas é opicional, não há problemas em deixar como está), sobre o [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864) mais um link que pode ajudar. Se não pretende trocar seu banco de dados talvez mysqli seja a melhor opção pelo ganho de performance